# Verbal algebra question confusion

Tags: linear-algebra

A student bought 10 red books and 4 green books. He paid 72 dollars for these books. We know that green books cost 10% more than red books.

A. find the price of each book types.

Ok:

$10x + 1.1(4x) = 72 => x_1 = 5, x_2 = 5.5$

So we know red = 5 and green = 5.5

But now they asked the following:

red books got cheaper by 8% but green books did not change.

Student A purchased 11 red books and student B purchased 8 green books.
Find which student out of A and B paid more and find by how many percent he paid more than the other student.

Ok so.. 8% less of 5 is:

$5 * 0.92 = 4.6$

so $11 * 4.6 = 50.6$

and $8 * 5.5 = 44$

Now to find the difference I use the following formula:

$ \dfrac{( |v_1 - v_2| )}{((|v_1 + v_2|) / 2)} \cdot 100$

so:

$ \dfrac{( |50.6 - 44| )}{((|50.6 + 44|) / 2)} \cdot 100 = 13.9%$

but the real answer is 15%.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The:

> percent he paid **more than the other student**

is: $\dfrac{v_1-v_2}{v_2} \times 100 =\dfrac{50.6-44}{44}\times 100=15 $

Comment: I see but why do you need to divide by $v_2$?

Comment: because the problem ask the percent paied **more the other student** not more the media (average expenditure).